# Refactoring BEGIN TRY/CATCH Statements for Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's possible to refactoring these queries:

```
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION SET ID_PRECISION = 9 WHERE ID_PRECISION = 2
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DELETE FROM  ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION WHERE ID_PRECISION = 2;
END CATCH; 
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION SET ID_PRECISION = 9 WHERE ID_PRECISION = 3
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DELETE FROM  ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION WHERE ID_PRECISION = 3;
END CATCH; 
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION SET ID_PRECISION = 9 WHERE ID_PRECISION = 8
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DELETE FROM  ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION WHERE ID_PRECISION = 8;
END CATCH; 
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION SET ID_PRECISION = 12 WHERE ID_PRECISION = 7
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DELETE FROM  ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION WHERE ID_PRECISION = 7;
END CATCH;
```

***Info:***

The Constraint Key on my table

```
ALTER TABLE ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION ADD  CONSTRAINT PK_ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_ETAT_PERSONNE] ASC,
    [ID_PRECISION] ASC
)
```

Comment: @Heinzi i delete because i have a `contraint key` on this table

Comment: So, if the following records (id_etat_personne, id_precision) exist: `(1, 2)`, `(1, 9)`, `(2, 2)`, `(3, 2)`, the first try/catch block would delete *all four* of them. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @Heinzi `id_precision (2,3,7,8)` was obsolete i want to update all `id_precision (2,3,8)`  
towards `id_precision = 9` and for `id_precision (7)` towards `id_precision = 12`

Comment: @Heinzi i want records (id_etat_personne, id_precision) exist: `(1,2)`,`(1,3)`,`(1,8)` become `(1,9)` and `(1,7)` become `(1,12)`

Comment: What @Heinzi is wondering about is do you really need to delete (2, 2) [and (3, 2)]  because there exists (1,9) while  (2,9) doesn't exists  ?

Comment: What kind of error are you expecting on `update` if you know exactly what  to set to `ID_PRECISION`? And again - why are you deleting in case of error? And you forgot to ask about "performance".

Comment: @Serg: Yes, that's exactly my question. Mercer: Is that what you want? If not, your current solution is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single update by doing this:

```
UPDATE ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION
    SET ID_PRECISION = (CASE WHEN ID_PRECISION = 7 THEN 12 ELSE 9 END)
    WHERE ID_PRECISION IN (2, 3, 8, 7);
```

I'm not sure why the row would be deleted if the update fails.  If the update fails, then the delete probably also fails.

Comment: When i do this request i have an error  on the `CONSTRAINT` i post this

Comment: @Mercer . . . I don't see why this would produce a constraint violation where your query would not.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need first process updatable rows instead. And then delete all the rest.

```
-- updatebale
UPDATE epp SET ID_PRECISION = 9 
FROM ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION epp
WHERE epp.ID_PRECISION IN (2,3,8) AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1  
   FROM ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION epp2
   WHERE epp2.ID_PRECISION = 9 and epp2.[ID_PRECISION] = epp.ID_PRECISION]);
--  unupdatable
DELETE FROM ETAT_PERSONNE_PRECISION WHERE ID_PRECISION IN (2,3,8)
```

Same with 7 -> 12

Comment: Error message: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword ' SELECT' .`